# Difference between "вставать" and "встать"

Tags: выбор-слова, синонимы

That's it, specifically in the sentences:

> не встать!

and

> не вставать!

Are they exactly the same, what are the differences?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Встать* and *вставать* are an aspectual pair (**видовая пара**) where *встать* is perfective and *вставать* is imperfective; otherwise their meaning is the same.  Their past forms (singular masculine) are *встал* and *вставал*, their future forms (singular first person) are *встану* and *буду вставать*.  In the present time, they are the same (встаю/встаём/встаёшь/встаёте/встаёт/встают).

*Встать* denotes a one-time action and *вставать* denotes a repeating action. For example, you can say "я вставал каждое утро", but not "я встал каждое утро", which is gramatically incorrect.

Sometimes, *встать* means a simple action, *вставать* means an action with internal structure.  For instance, "надо встать" refers to a physical action of standing up or raising from the bed. "Надо вставать" means that one needs to get up, which takes time.

Some more examples:

- Waking up somebody, the correct verb is "вставай(те)", not "встань(те)", because a sleeping person cannot raise immediately, the process takes time.
- But "Я встану завтра в 7 утра", "завтра мне надо встать в 7 утра" - because the process of getting up will/should be finished at 7.  Similarly, "я вчера встал в 7 утра", because at 7am you already finished the process of getting up.  "Я вчера вставал в 7 утра" means, if anything, that at 7am you were in bed making heroic efforts to get up.
- When doing physical exercises, "встань(те)" (встали, встать) is the correct verb, because it refers to a physical movement.
- When sitting in a train, "вставай, мы приехали" means that the train is at the destination station, and you ask the person to stand up, but before it he may put his book into the bag, for example.  "Встань" in the train means that you want him to stand up immediately.

---

"Не вставать!" is an order prohibiting to stand up.  "Не встать" is a phrase, not a sentence, meaning that it is impossible to stand up or get up (due to weariness, wounds, absence of space to stand up, etc.)

Also, there is a colloquial phrase "умереть, не встать" ("упасть, не встать", "не встать") which means "very funny", "LOLMAO"

Comment: In present time (you probably mean 'in the present _tense_') they are not the same, встаю/встаём/встаёшь etc. are actually the forms of the imperfective, вставать. The forms of the perfective, встать, with the same present tense suffixes are встану/встанешь/встанет etc., they are used as the future tense. In other words,
imperfective verb + present tense suffixes = present tense form of the verb; 
perfective verb + present tense suffixes = future tense form of the verb.

Comment: Not true.  Встану - future perfective.  Встаю - present, both perfective and imperfective.  Буду вставать - future imperfective.  Examples: "я встаю в данный момент" - "я встаю каждый день" - both are correct.

Comment: Also, you write "встаю/встаём/встаёшь etc. are actually the forms of the imperfective, вставать".   The forms of "вставать" (as opposite to встать) would be вставаю, вставаем etc. but there are no such words/forms in Russian.

Comment: Firstly, it _is_ true technically, morphologically. If you take another imperf./perf. pair of verbs, e.g. писать/написать, you'll see that it's impossible to make present tense forms of написать. Secondly, both "в данный момент" and "каждый день" are typical adverbial modifiers of the imperfective forms (i.e. they have either the meaning of the English Continuous or Indefinite aspects), but perfective forms are characterized by something different, by implying the action has either a beginning or an end. So, `вставать` means either "get up usually, regularly" or "be getting up right now". >>>

Comment: Firstly, it is true for the verb "писать", but not for the verb "вставать".  (Писать - пишу, but not вставать - "вставаю").  Secondly, if what you right is true, then there is no such thing as present perfective.

Comment: >>> `встать` means "begin getting up" or "finish getting up, become standing, or not sleeping". As for "*вставаю", everybody knows that the "-ва" suffix disappears in the present tense forms: `давать - даю, рисовать - рисую`.

Comment: "встать means "begin getting up" or "finish getting up, become standing, or not sleeping"" - thats exactly what I wrote in my answer.  "As for "*вставаю", everybody knows that the "-ва" suffix disappears in the present tense forms: давать - даю, рисовать - рисую." - not (always) true, i.e. обрисовал - обрисовываю.

Comment: Because of the very nature of the perfective aspect the present perfective forms of verbs can mean nothing else but the future tense.

Comment: `Oбрисовал` is past perf., `обрисовываю` is pres. imperf., and the pres. perf. of the latter verb (which has the future meaning) is `обрисую`, "-ва" disappears. And there are cases when this statement of yours is wrong: _Встать means one-time action_: `Ему потребовалось 5 лет чтобы встать на ноги.` Look, you're trying to prove things which are not actually true, editing your answer at the same time. You must read more on the Russian aspect. We can move the discussion to chat and I can help you understand the whole thing, I'm a native speaker of Russian, a linguist, and a teacher.

Comment: I am also a native speaker of Russian, and, thank God, not a teacher.  Neither I am a linguist.  Being a teacher, you stick to concepts which you read in textbooks, which are detached from reality.

Comment: As for editing my answer, I did it to add several examples, and add the information.  You, teacher, are trying to hint that I did it in response to your comments in our discussion, which is not true.  "pres. perf. of the latter verb (which has the future meaning)" is just a world salad.  Present can not have a "future meaning".  Present from рисовать is рисую, present from обрисовывать is обрисовываю.

Comment: Each word has its form and meaning, the relation between them is what you're missing. In case of perf./imperf. pairs, perfective verbs that formally look like present tense verbs (because they have the present tense suffixes) are used _only_ with future meaning: e.g. ехать/уехать - ед**у** and уед**у** have identical present tense suffixes, but уед**у** means _only_ future, while ед**у** means _both_ present and future: `Я сейчас ед**у** домой. / Завтра я ед**у** домой.` Note, what's called "future" has a present suffix, what's called "present" means also future.

Comment: In school, we were taught that perfective forms answer the question "что сделать?" (or a corresponding grammatical variation: "сделал/сделали/сделаю/сделаешь/..."), while imperfective ones, "что делать?" (or a variation, including future tense forms: "что буду/будешь/etc. делать?"). From that, the rule was simple: if the verb in the question has the "с-" prefix, then the verb we are examining is a perfective verb, otherwise an imperfective one. "Встаю" answers the question "что делаю?", and by that rule it's an imperfective verb.

Comment: *"and вставать denotes a repeating action"*, — this is a bit misleading, it also denotes a currently being performed action. That is "я встаю" can mean not only "I rise" but "I'm rising" too

Comment: in regard to aspectual pair and negation, my favorite example is the opposite meaning of "не скажи" (don't tell, emphatic disagreement) и "не говори" (don't say, emphatic agreement), while in positive forms the verbs are overlapping in meanings. It took me a while to rationalize this :-D

Comment: @AndriyM this rule of thumb it helpful for persons, who grew up in the language environment. They "sucked in" the language patterns when playing in the street with peers from the youngest years. They just do not rationalize while this and that is correct. But they perfectly can match the verb like that with the questioning form. So, it is a memory device, not an explanation. A foreigner would not have that childhood memories and innated patterns, one would not be able to tell "what question is correct or not"

Comment: @Arioch: I'm not sure now but I think the point I was trying to make at the time is that *встаю* (along with the other present tense forms) is a form of just *вставать* rather than both *вставать* and *встать*. The OP seems to claim (or at least their wording might mislead one to conclude) the latter in the answer's first paragraph: "In the present time, they are the same".

Comment: @AndriyM the answer says "otherwise [than perfect/imperfect pair] their meaning is the same". I think you said the same thing. My point was, memorizing tricks like "ask the matching question" do not work on foreigners, only on natives.

Comment: @Arioch: Sorry, just read the other comments in the thread. My comment was most likely a direct reply to the OP's comment where they are explicitly stating, " Встаю - present, both perfective and imperfective."

Comment: @AndriyM встаю clearly is continuous, that is not perfect[ive]. I'd say there is no true present for perfective verbs: if you are in the middle of activity, then it is not complete=perfected yet

Comment: @Arioch: Yes, that's what I got out of my school years as well (that there's no perfective in present tense). But then, I was taught Russian in school at the time when my home country was called Soviet Union. It's Ukraine now, so maybe something has changed since then (in terms of grammar rules) that I'm not in a good position to know about. I mean, if words like *встаю* are now considered both perfective and imperfective, I might still disagree as it doesn't make much sense to me, but at this point I'm just not aware whether or not anything has changed, so...

Comment: @AndriyM I do not remember in Soviet schools in Russia even mentioning of aspect pairs. I think it only matters for linguists and for foreigners educations. Native speakers innate this knowledge in early childhood without ever rationalizing it, so no point to put it into elementary school textbooks. Personally, I only became partially understanding it, reflecting it, when I learned English and was comparing how similar/different were methods Russian and English languages used to convey same concepts. In xxxSSR schools, where Russian could be seen as foreign language, it maybe was different.

Comment: What on earth are you guys arguing about. It's clear to any 1st year student of Russian that вставать шы imperfective and yes the -ва- part disappears. And no there's no such thing as a perfective in the present. обрисовать--that's a different verb conjugation form, like советовать, итд. This is one case it's much easier for a foreigner to see what's going on. I can't believe the number of comments on something a student 3 months into a program of Russian could tell you :)

Answer (score 4):

The difference between these two words is a usual difference between a pair of an imperfective (вставать) and a perfective (встать) verbs.

Besides, `не встать!` looks ungrammatical as imperative, perfective verbs are not used in negative (forbidding) imperative commands (the `!` suggests you meant it to be imperative), although it is possible to use the phrase to express regret, then it means `cannot stand/get up!`

`Не вставать!` is a usual strongly forbidding imperative command, it means `don't you stand/get up!`

Comment: Thank you. I had seen perfective aspects were generally made adding prefixes to the verb, so I wasn't identifying these two as them. Thank again, and yes, I was referring to the imperative form.

Comment: Final question, Are those correct as imperative sentences, would one shouldn't use встава́й or вста́нь if using perfective form as you said?

Comment: Sorry, but I can't completely understand your final question, will you reformulate it? `Встава́й!` (imperfective) and `вста́нь!` (perfective) are both correct imperatives ("Stand/get up!") and mean almost the same, the difference is `встава́й!` _can_ be used when speaking about regular, repeated, habitual action, like when you tell a person when she must usually get up: `Вставай в 7 часов утра каждый день!` ("Get up at 7 a.m. every day!"), `вста́нь!` can't be used in such cases, when a repeated action is implied. That's, probably, the only difference between those two imperatives.

Comment: See examples in my edited reply.

Answer (score 2):

To put it simpler, I will try to link both finitive and infinitive forms of a verb with tenses that you would use in English language.
Notice that this probably applies to any of such a pair of words.

As a rule of thumb...

Continuous and Perfect Continuous tenses all would be translated through the useof imperfective form (**вставать**, **делать**). Such as "I am standing up right now!" ("Я **встаю** прямо сейчас!") or "I will be standing up when you come in." ("Я **буду вставать**, когда ты войдёшь."

All the Perfect tenses, as you would guess, are translated with the perfective form, "**встать**, **сделать**".

As for Simple (Indefinite) tenses, it is not that "simple". :) Present Indefinite I can clearly link to the imperfective form, I couldn't come up with any examples of the opposite. For example, ("I [wake up/leave my bed] at 7 a.m. every day.", "Я каждый день **встаю** в 7 утра"). With Past and Future Indefinite tenses you should check if you can substitute this tense for any other without losing the meaning. Let's call it "defining" an Indefinite tense. :)

For example, "I will do my homework". "**Делать**" or "**сделать**"? Let's "define" it! Perhaps, you can rephrase it in Continuous form? For example: "I will be doing my homework". Then use "Я буду **делать** домашнее задание". Can you use Perfect tense, for example, "I will have done my homework by Monday"? "Я **сделаю** домашнюю работу к понедельнику".

If you can, go ahead and use the instructions provided above.

If even this doesn't help, try to understand if the action itself is spoken about as finished or unfinished. It is very important.

Good luck with your learning.

Answer (score 1):

> не встать!
>
> And
>
> не вставать!

Probably the better answer here should sound on the Russian language, let me give you answer:

Не встать! - Например, "Эй Вась, Мне не встать!" - это означает, что не возможно подняться. Очень тяжело. Или угроза: "Тебе не встать!", это может означать, что условия будут такими, что встать ты не сможешь, имей это ввиду, даже не пытайся. Или как предупреждение.

В то время как "Не вставать!", это либо приказ, либо рекомендация. Т.е. то чего не стоит делать. "Нельзя вставать!". Здесь "НЕ" может быть без ошибки заменено словом "НЕЛЬЗЯ". Хотя, в предыдущем примере, тоже.

В тоже время, когда я увидел заголовок вопроса, я прочитал его совершенно иначе, я не видел слова "не", и восклицательного знака. `Difference between вставать and встать` - Разнится между двумя словами встать и вставать.

Встать: Я пытаюсь встать. Мне надо встать.

Или приказ: "Встать ! Смирно !" - Типичный приказ лежащим по званию ниже.

В то время как, "Вставать !", более мягкая форма, но далеко не просьба.

Я пытался вставать. Я пытаюсь вставать. Мне надо вставать.
Более ленивая, и в тоже время абсолютно идентичная по смысле форма одного и того же выражения.

Приказ может звучать, абсолютно идентично по тону: "Вставать!"

Более короткая форма "Встать" - более резкая. Так всегда.

> Are they exactly the same, what are the differences?

They are exactly the same. Differences only in shorter little bit more sharp.

But in your case. `Не встать!`, one person signal another or his group, that **he can not**.

`Не вставать!` - One person signal another or his group, that "they should not вставать!" Waiting for something, or something is detected, that is why, Stop ! Do not get up !

E.g. it can not be vice verse. One person can not signal group "Не встать!", to stop them from standing up. It will mean "I can not get up !". Or "Here, is not possible to standing up !".

And again "Не вставать !", can not be used to self. It is broadcast.