# conjugate признавать

Tags: словоупотребление, вид

Apparently *признавать* conjugates the same like the verb with perfective aspect *признать*.

Thus present and future conjugates

```
Singular  
признаю, -ешь, -ет  
Plural  
признаем, -ете, -ют
```

- Is that right?
- What kind of verb is it?
- How to distinguish present and future then?
- and does it affect the future with a form of `быть` (e. g. `буду` + `признать / признавать`)?

Comment: Have a look at the answer to this question http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/2805/difference-between-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-and-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C. It answers your question completely

Comment: @cha yea, but it seems `встану` is future and `встаю` is present. But `признаю` is future *and* present in one form, is it?

Comment: It is not. Future has the stress on "а", present on "ю". Though they are indeed written the same.

Comment: @shady_arc okay. did not look carefully. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ia an imperfective/perfective pair of verbs, `признавать` is imperfective, `признать` is perfective. The forms of the two verbs are written the same way, but they are distinguished with the stress which is usually not marked in writing, although sometimes it can be marked to get rid of ambiguity.

`Признавáть` (imp.) has the stress on the suffix, just like the infinitive, these forms have the meaning of the Present tense:

```
Singular
признаю́, признаёшь, признаёт
Plural
признаём, признаёте, признаю́т
```

`Признáть` (perf.) has the stress on the root, just like the infinitive, these forms have the meaning of the Future tense:

```
Singular
признáю, признáешь, признáет
Plural
признáем, признáете, признáют
```

Only `признавать` can have the Future tense formed with "быть": `буду признавать` (will acknowledge).

Answer (score 0):

- я признаю
- ты признаёшь
- она признаёт
- мы признаём
- вы признаёте
- они признают

It is an end-stressed verb, unlike stem-stressed "признать". Imperfective aspect. They don't have one single form where they sound the same. Better check *gramota.ru* next time. At least, they always have Ё when needed.

To answer your last question, "compound" future with "быть" only ever uses imperfective verbs. So use "признавать".