# "Встань" or "встать"?

Tags: глаголы, повелительное-наклонение

I was listening to song `Играть, чтобы жить`, by `Павел Пламенев`. Something is really bothering me in the lyrics. I understand the song well, vocabulary is not a problem for me here. Except this:

```
Ты сам себе сказал:
- Встать!
```

Shouldn't it be...?

```
Ты сам себе сказал:
- Встань!
```

After all it is an imperative, there is even an exclamation mark, isn't it? What do I am missing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both forms are correct.

"Встань" - is for "[you,] stand up!" - it's the imperative form. "Встать!" is the infinitive form that also can be used in modern Russian as an imperative. The difference is that infinitive imperative is more command-like, hard and generally speaking more offensive.

A policemen can shout out: "Встать!", but mother would tell her son: "Встань". A lover can ask: "Смотри мне в глаза", a detective can yell at the suspect:  "В глаза мне смотреть!".

The other difference is the `встань` is for a singular you ("ты" in Russian), for referring group of people - or just being polite - one should use `встаньте`. "Встать" is correct both for "ты" and "вы".

**UPD:** as of what's the difference between `встать` and `вставать` - this is perfectly covered [here](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/2805/difference-between-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-and-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C).

Comment: Thank you @shabunc, no grammar book I've searched had this information. I was inclined to guess that, but also in need of someone to confirm it.

Comment: @C.Bohok I think by using infinitive form the ordering side stresses total absence of personal communication, only formal interaction based upon authority/power non-equivalence. That is why it sounds more harsh. It is "chemically pure" bossing around, while in imperative form it is more or less mixed with some person-to-person link.